# Lucene IndexWriter slow to add documents

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I wrote a small loop which added 10,000 documents into the IndexWriter and it took for ever to do it.

Is there another way to index large volumes of documents?

I ask because when this goes live it has to load in 15,000 records.

The other question is how do I prevent having to load in all the records again when the web application is restarted?

**Edit**

Here is the code i used;

```
for (int t = 0; t < 10000; t++){
    doc = new Document();
    text = "Value" + t.toString();
    doc.Add(new Field("Value", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
    iwriter.AddDocument(doc);
};
```

**Edit 2**

```
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();

        IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true);

        iwriter.SetMaxFieldLength(25000);
```

then the code to add the documents, then;

```
        iwriter.Close();
```

Comment: it took around 2.5 to 3 minutes.  Is this to be expected?

Comment: I should add that the docs contained a single field and that the field had "value " + t.toString() as its value.  So very small

Comment: Can we see the code you used to set the index writer up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just checking, but you haven't got the debugger attached when you're running it have you?

This severely affects performance when adding documents.

On my machine (Lucene 2.0.0.4):

Built with platform target x86:

- No debugger - 5.2 seconds
- Debugger attached - 113.8 seconds

Built with platform target x64:

- No debugger - 6.0 seconds
- Debugger attached - 171.4 seconds

Rough example of saving and loading an index to and from a RAMDirectory:

```
const int DocumentCount = 10 * 1000;
const string IndexFilePath = @"X:\Temp\tmp.idx";

Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
Directory ramDirectory = new RAMDirectory();

IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(ramDirectory, analyzer, true);

for (int i = 0; i < DocumentCount; i++)
{
    Document doc = new Document();
    string text = "Value" + i;
    doc.Add(new Field("Value", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
    indexWriter.AddDocument(doc);
}

indexWriter.Close();

//Save index
FSDirectory fileDirectory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(IndexFilePath, true);
IndexWriter fileIndexWriter = new IndexWriter(fileDirectory, analyzer, true);
fileIndexWriter.AddIndexes(new[] { ramDirectory });
fileIndexWriter.Close();

//Load index
FSDirectory newFileDirectory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(IndexFilePath, false);
Directory newRamDirectory = new RAMDirectory();
IndexWriter newIndexWriter = new IndexWriter(newRamDirectory, analyzer, true);
newIndexWriter.AddIndexes(new[] { newFileDirectory });

Console.WriteLine("New index writer document count:{0}.", newIndexWriter.DocCount());
```

Comment: +1, thank for this i'll look into this tonight.  i suspect it may be the debugger now that you mention it.  thanks for your help

Comment: thanks for your help.  i'm not quite getting the great times you are.  mine is at 16secs which is acceptable i think.  i think it's down to my hardwear now.

Answer (score 10):

You should do this way to get the best performance. on my machine i'm indexing 1000 document in 1 second

1) You should reuse (Document, Field) not creating every time you add a document like this

```
private static void IndexingThread(object contextObj)
{
     Range<int> range = (Range<int>)contextObj;
     Document newDoc = new Document();
     newDoc.Add(new Field("title", "", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
     newDoc.Add(new Field("body", "", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
     newDoc.Add(new Field("newsdate", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
     newDoc.Add(new Field("id", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));

     for (int counter = range.Start; counter <= range.End; counter++)
     {
         newDoc.GetField("title").SetValue(Entities[counter].Title);
         newDoc.GetField("body").SetValue(Entities[counter].Body);
         newDoc.GetField("newsdate").SetValue(Entities[counter].NewsDate);
         newDoc.GetField("id").SetValue(Entities[counter].ID.ToString());

         writer.AddDocument(newDoc);
     }
}
```

After that you could use threading and break your large collection into smaller ones, and use the above code for each section
for example if you have 10,000 document you can create 10 Thread using ThreadPool and feed each section to
one thread for indexing

Then you will gain the best performance.