# Document-wrapper in Lucene.NET does not work

Tags: c#, lucene

I'm using Lucene and having a a wrapper-class for my documents indexed by lucene. This wrapper-class contains internally an instance of *Lucene.Net.Documents.Document*. It looks like this:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public Document Document { get; private set; }

    public Wrapper()
    {
        this.Document  = new Document();

        // Adding fields here...
        Document.Add(new Field("ID", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the ID.
    /// </summary>
    public string ID
    {
        get { return this.Document.GetField("ID").StringValue; }
        set { this.Document.GetField("ID").SetValue(value); }
    }

    ...
}
```

I use the wrapper for easy handling. In case I want to create a new record to add to the index I'm doing the following:

```
var w = new Wrapper();
w.ID = "5";

var writer = new IndexWriter(...);
writer.Add(w.Document);
```

**My problem is that the indexed record is totally empty.** Whereas when I debug the application and check the variable "Document-property of the wrapper-instance I can find all values. But they are not stored in the index.

Any ideas about that?

My further findings up to now:

In comparison to that I found out that using no wrapper ... like the following ... is working fine:

```
var d = new Document();
d.Add(new Field("ID", "5", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

var writer = new IndexWriter(...);
writer.Add(d);
```

I found this question+answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364651/1623426 He is doing a similar thing. But where is my problem?

Comment: Looks all right to me.  I tried indexing with your wrapper class and was able to search for documents and retrieve the ID value from the results docs.  [Here is the code I used to test it](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f2e18725c90b0d9a7755).  Perhaps the code you've posted isn't enough to reproduce the issue?

Comment: You didn't post the whole code, so: did you commit the changes to the index and opened the reader afterwards? Did you use a near-realtime reader? If you answered *no* to both questions, that's your issue.

Comment: Committing changes YES, but no closing the IndexWriter. Opening the IndexSearcher afterwards YES. Near-realtime-reader NO.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I used (as written in my example)

```
writer.Add(document);
```

...instead of...

```
writer.AddDocument(document);
```

:/

The wrapper is working fine. I found it by comparing with femtoRgons example.